# How to get next element with following-sibling?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

**Problem 1**: How to click on next `div` element with same class (separate page), scrape the page, go back and click next `div` element? Since all elements have the same class name, and contains a unique link to separate pages which I would like to scrape, the problem then becomes that I need to Find element->Go to page->Scrape the info->Go back->Go to next element and so on. **Solved:**

**Problem 2**: How can I make the printing to CSV print Text and NOT xpath paths. See code used below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver.get('https://www.example.com/list/')

# Loop load more in list
loadmore = True

while loadmore:
    try:
        next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="show-more"]')
        next_link.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        rows_remaining = False

# Open Csv file
File = open('list.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(File)
entries = [] # defines entries
writer.writerows((entries))

# Collect all the elements
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='/stockholm/']")

# Loop through each element to scrape
urls=[]
for element in elements:
    urls.append(element.get_attribute('href'))
    print(element.get_attribute('href')) # gets the href value of the element

# Define Xpath
def get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
    return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    facts = [
    ("//div[@class='fact' and contains(span, '')][1]"),
    ("//div[@class='fact' and contains(span, '')][2]"),]
    for name, xpath in facts:
        entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath))
    writer.writerow(facts)
```

This is the code used for printing to CSV while on a single page and without for-looping the URLs:

```
facts = [
    ("//div[@class='fact' and contains(span, '')][1]"),
    ("//div[@class='fact' and contains(span, '')][2]"),]


with open('list.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    entries = []
    for name, xpath in facts:
        entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath))
    writer.writerows(zip(*entries))
```

Comment: Should you be writing the entries into csv instead of facts? writer.writerow(entries) ?

Comment: I tried doing that but it won't print anything. When putting facts inside `writerows()` I get the paths for facts printed correctly which is half-way there. When I do this setup using `with open` it works but then the `writer.writerows` has `(zip(*entries))` instead of just entries. Presumably there is some kind of headache here since the original open with just contained a plural writerowS and the new code is singular writeroW. Can't get my head around this one :(

Comment: @Sureshmani I've added the original code when printing to CSV from one page only. Perhaps it helps to understand the logic from it. As you can see **facts** are presented before **entries=[]** and writing to CSV. Perhaps this calls for a nested loop?

Comment: I think name is a invalid argument for this 'for' loop - see my updated answer

Comment: @Sureshmani Sorry for late reply and I tried this. For some reason it won't print anything to my csv file (it creates an empty file) but in the terminal window it does show what it was sopposed to print using the `print(entries)`. I used the exact same code and the html-source has not changed so it can't be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use following siblings. you can find all the div using find_elements which returns a list. After this you can loop through each element and scrape what you need.

```
    # Collect all the elements
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='/stockholm/']")

# Loop through each element to scrape
urls=[]
for element in elements:
    urls.append(element.get_attribute('href'))
    print(element.get_attribute('href')) # gets the href value of the element

# Define Xpath
def get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath):
    return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]

# Open Csv file
File = open('list.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(File)

for url in urls:
    print(url) # Check if the url is correct
    driver.get(url)
    entries = [] # defines entries - Reset to blank after each loop
    facts = [
    ("//div[@class='fact' and contains(span, '')][1]"),
    ("//div[@class='fact' and contains(span, '')][2]"),]
    for xpath in facts:
        entries.append(get_elements_by_xpath(driver, xpath))
    print(entries) #Check what you are writing into csv file before writing
    writer.writerow(entries)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I now see that I missed one detail: Each element contains a link to a unique page. On that page is the info which I would like to scrape. The problem then becomes that I need to Find elemtn->Go to page->Scrape the info->Go back->Go to next element and so on. For this, as I understand it, following-sibling must be the way to go?

Comment: Navigating back & forth may cause stale element exceptions. Instead you can grap all the urls and loop through it - see updated answer.

Comment: That was amazing. Kudos - it worked better than I expected and was exactly what I was looking for! It also widened my view on how to apply this technique even further. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: I've got one last question for you though in `for url in urls:` under `# Scrape what you need`: How can I write the data directly to a CSV file? Doing it the way my original script was designed does not really work and since this is a for-loop I presume I need to do a nested loop where retrieving the data is first `driver.get(url)` while the second is `with open('name.csv', 'a') as f:` and so on. I tried doing a nested loop but it didn't work to `with open` nor did it retrieve any data if I used the `with open` after all URL's had been scanned. I feel there is something missing

Comment: See updated answer. The csv file can be opened before the loop and writerow method is used to write a item to csv file.

Comment: Thanks, this works but it prints the xpath's element path instead of printing the text contained within the path. The way I scripted originally was by `def xpath(driver, xpath)` and `return [entry.text for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)]`. The paths is then coded: `facts = [("Fact 1", "//div[@class='call']"), ("Fact 2", "//div[@class='apt-fact'[1]"), ("Fact 3", "//div[@class='apt-fact'][2]"),]`. At the end, after `with open`, I scripted `entries=[]` followed by a `for name, xpath in facts: entries.append(get_element...xpath(driver, xpath)`. How can I do it here?